# Open-source solutions for creating a cyclical logfile?

Tags: c, logging, embedded

```
if (!wheel) { wheel = new Wheel(); }   // or some such
```

My google goggles aren't working too well today. I figured this one must have been coded a gazillion times already and was looking for some FOSS code, but couldn't find any.

Before I reinvent the spherical axle-surrounding device, can anyone point me at a URL?

I am coding in C for an embedded system (Atmel UC3), but that shouldn't make any difference, just explain why I need a cyclical logfile (because of limited storage).

I want to log events to a file on an SD card and when the reaches a certain size I want to start writing again at the start. Any URLs for that?  (fixed entry size is ok; otherwise it might get nasty on wraparound).

Thanks a 1,000,000 in advance!

Comment: You probably actually want a circular axle-surrounding device (as well as a circular logfile), not a spherical one!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sourceforge has a project called [Cyclic Logs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cycliclogs/) which may be what you need.

If not, it's not the hardest thing to implement. Just treat it like a normal cyclic memory space. But instead of having it be resident in memory have it reside on the disk.

( maintain a pointer to the head of the log and the end of the log ( increment as needed ))

Store those as headers to the log or as another flat file.

Comment: +1 and the answer.  And a resounding D'oh!! from me. I was already at SF but stupidly searched for "Cyclical", not "cyclic".  Thanks a 1,000,000

Comment: Yep, cyclic memory space. For one of my projects I use a 1 GB file memory mapped on disk for the log. It uses a custom C++ `streambuf`. A simple binary `and` operation makes the pointer wrap. Pretty easy.